# Multiple dynamic background image urls based on screen size

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to use two different background-image:url() values based on screen size.  This is fairly simple to do if the urls are known ahead of time:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.element {
    background-image:url("/Images/1.png");
}
}

@media (min-width: 401px) {
.element {
    background-image:url("/Images/2.png");
}
}
```

However, I do not know my image urls ahead of time - they are based on information from the user.  I can set a single background-image:url() dynamically in the code behind like so:

```
string backgroundStyle = "background-image: url(\""+loginImagePath+"\"); ";
sBodyWrapper.Attributes.Add("style", backgroundStyle);
```

But I'm not sure how I might go about setting two different background images which alternatively show based on screen width.  I could set the two background images on different elements and hide one of those elements, but I really would like this background image to be on a single body wrapping element.
Is there any way to set values inside of media queries?  Can conditional css be applied on the element's style attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the conditional CSS via a style tag appended to the document:

```
var rules = '<style>
@media(max-width: 400px){
  background-image:url("Images/1.png");
}
@media(min-width: 401px){
  background-image:url("Images/2.png");
}
</style>';
```

Comment: This is a pretty hacky solution, but it works.  Thanks for your help - even though I've done something similar before, I didn't think to use this strategy.